# Forwarding packets through a host

Tags: linux, firewall, routing, openvpn

I've setup a Site-to-Site network using [this How To](https://docs.openvpn.net/how-to-tutorialsguides/virtual-platforms/site-to-site-layer-3-routin-using-openvpn-access-server/)

This How To fits exactly what I need.

But I've a problem.
From site wich hosting the OpenVPN AS server (site 2, right in the howto) I can't ping a machine wich is in the site 1 (left in the howto).
*But* OpenVPN AS server can ping the remote site.

Comment: It's better to you grep -v ^$ your_config_files and put into post and expalin more about error.

Comment: I can't find config files for OpenVPN AS. I have a file, but it doesn't help for this matter.
I have a site A wich hosting a VPN server. I have a site B wich hosting client machines.
Site B is connected remotely to site A with OpenVPN. The VPN client on the site B is the gateway so clients on site B can all ping site A via VPN.
The VPN server on site A is not the gateway so I have to add a route in site A clients to tell them where to go to reach site B (it's my problem, I'm agree with this).

Comment: To do this, I've followed the howto mentionned in the first post.
Pings pass from site B to site A but not the inverse.